Shortcut key for adding adding http://www.<site>.com in DuckDuckGo
In Chrome & Edge when typing a website and pressing Control+Enter, http://www..com is automatically added. In DuckDuckGo I'm seeing this same behavior. Is there a key combination for this in DuckDuckGo?

What do you mean by pressing control+Enter gives you http://www..com? it's just not doing anything

It's only the address bar that will allow ctrl+enter, not a html form's input field, but you could do it with a javascript.
